# How do I change my wallpaper?

Tags: recettear-an-item-shops-tale

I just hit merchant level 6, which allows me to "choose a new wallpaper for your store, if you have one."

I went to the market and bought new wallpaper, but I can't seem to figure out how to apply it. Tear doesn't seem to give me the option, and I"m not quite sure where else to look for the option.

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is very obvious, once you stop looking for it, and continue with the day.

You can change it from behind the counter, the same location as where you start the next part of the day.